# how to compress a sitemap with php

Tags: php, xml, compression, gzip, sitemap

I have this below code and it work fine

```
        header ("content-type: text/xml");
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
        $xml .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitepam/0.84">';
        $xml .= '<url><loc>'.SiteRoot.'</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>1.0</priority></url>';
        $xml .= '<url><loc>'.SiteRoot.'/directory</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>0.9</priority></url>';
        $Query = mysql_query ("SELECT link FROM `om` ORDER BY `link`");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Query)) {
            $xml .= '<url>';
            $xml .= '<loc>'.GenerateLink( 'link',$row['link'] ).'</loc>';
            $xml .= '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>';
            $xml .= '<priority>0.8</priority>';
            $xml .= '</url>';
        }
        $xml .= '</urlset>';
        echo $xml;
```

When i try to compress it with mime header

```
header('content-type: application/x-gzip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sitemap.xml.gz"');
```

Browser download a `.gz` file but it's not open. winrar give me a error that said: *The archive is either in unknown format or damaged*

This is the final code :

```
    //  header ("content-type: text/xml");
        header('content-type: application/x-gzip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sitemap.xml.gz"');
        $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
        $xml .= '<urlset xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitepam/0.84">';
        $xml .= '<url><loc>'.SiteRoot.'</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>1.0</priority></url>';
        $xml .= '<url><loc>'.SiteRoot.'/directory</loc><changefreq>daily</changefreq><priority>0.9</priority></url>';
        $Query = mysql_query ("SELECT link FROM `om` ORDER BY `link`");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Query)) {
            $xml .= '<url>';
            $xml .= '<loc>'.GenerateLink( 'link',$row['link'] ).'</loc>';
            $xml .= '<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>';
            $xml .= '<priority>0.8</priority>';
            $xml .= '</url>';
        }
        $xml .= '</urlset>';
        echo $xml;
```

Comment: sorry, but why are you trying to compress your sitemap?

Comment: Compressing large sitemaps is a quick and easy way to save bandwidth and is supported by most major search engines.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata My sitemap is very large.

Comment: Think about it that you can only put 50.000 urls into one xml sitemap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using some of the built in gzip functions like [`gzencode`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.gzencode.php)

```
echo gzencode($xml);
```

Comment: Glad to help, in fact, I am now doing the same for my sitemap

Comment: @kamal : can you post your final sitemap.xml file with gzencode